# SWTBot hangs at click

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, swtbot

I'm trying to automate a simple new project wizard using SwtBot 2.2.1 . The code is the one that I've found in the tutorial

```
bot.menu("File").menu("New").menu("Project...").click();
```

The problem is that the `click()` method call never returns. My target platform is Eclipse Kepler on Linux x86_64 . The new project dialog is brought up however, so I'm not sure why the call does not return. Here's a screenshot of what the Eclipse instance under test looks like when the test hangs

[image: swtbot workspace]

The stack trace of the main thread is

```
"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007f12c0006000 nid=0x428b runnable [0x00007f12c68d2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.Call(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sleep(Display.java:4233)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:802)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.NewProjectAction.run(NewProjectAction.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1392)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1416)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1401)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1187)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.widgets.AbstractSWTBot$2.run(AbstractSWTBot.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.finders.UIThreadRunnable$5.doRun(UIThreadRunnable.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.finders.UIThreadRunnable.run(UIThreadRunnable.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.finders.UIThreadRunnable.asyncExec(UIThreadRunnable.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.widgets.AbstractSWTBot.asyncExec(AbstractSWTBot.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.widgets.AbstractSWTBot.notify(AbstractSWTBot.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.widgets.AbstractSWTBot.notify(AbstractSWTBot.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.widgets.AbstractSWTBot.notify(AbstractSWTBot.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.widgets.SWTBotMenu.click(SWTBotMenu.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.ide.test.impl.ui.NewContentPackageWizardTest.createNewContentProject(NewContentPackageWizardTest.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.junit.SWTBotJunit4ClassRunner.run(SWTBotJunit4ClassRunner.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.RemotePluginTestRunner.main(RemotePluginTestRunner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.PlatformUITestHarness$1.run(PlatformUITestHarness.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    - locked <0x00000000fe4fc480> (a org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3717)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3366)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.UITestApplication.runApp(UITestApplication.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

What can I do to make the test run successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My error was launching the tests on the UI thread. Once I unchecked 'Run on UI thread' in the launch configuration, the tests executed fine.